# using regex to split a string so It will return both whole and decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in the middle of a project where in the beginning I had the following string <=10 & <20 and I want to split this string so it gives the following results ('<=' '10' '<' '20') the & is irrelevant because I deal with that in a different area of my code!

this is the solution I have when it is whole numbers

```
.match(/(([<=>]+)|(\d+))/ig) - result: '<=' '10' '<' '20'
```

But the string can also have negative numbers <=1.2 & <2.2 and the results required from this would be ('<=' '1.2' '<' '2.2'). So how would I update the .match above to handle both scenarios.

Comment: Negative or decimal numbers?

Comment: decimal numbers and whole numbers. not negative numbers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the dot, use a class containing both the digits and the dot : `[\d.]`. You may also remove the superfluous parenthesis :

```
/([<=>]+)|([\d.]+)/ig
```

Example :

```
">= 2.2 & < 3.3".match(/([<=>]+)|([\d.]+)/ig)
```

gives

```
[">=", "2.2", "<", "3.3"]
```

Comment: while using the answer above regarding the following string              >= 2.2 & < 3.3 I get the following result '>=' '2.2' '&' '<' '3.' so the 3.3 isn't coming threw correctly

Comment: I just tested in the console and got the right result. Try it : `">= 2.2 & < 3.3".match(/(([<=>]+)|([\d.]+))/ig)`.

Comment: I retried it, it was a mistake on my part! thanks very much for the help :)